# Rails Delegate Not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following classes:

```
class VideoChannel < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Associations
  belongs_to :video_playlist, :dependent => :destroy
  VideoChannel.video_playlist_name 

  delegate :name, :id, :list_type, :list_id, :manual, :to => :video_playlist, :prefix => true

  #validations
  validates_presence_of :name

  #After Functions
  def after_create
    video_playlist = VideoPlaylist.new(:name      => self.name,
                                       :list_type => "VideoChannel",
                                       :list_id   => self.id)
    video_playlist.save
  end
```

And :

```
class VideoPlaylist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :list, :polymorphic => true

  has_many    :video_channels, :dependent => :destroy
  delegate :name, :id, :description, :to => :video_channel, :prefix => true

end
```

I'm trying to use the Rails Delegate function to create a link in the VideoChannel page that allows me to to link to the Video Playlist and edit the contents there.  So the association is there and You can currently edit the playlists by going through the playlists section but we want to combine them.  I can't seem to figure this out.  Im also very new to Rails, still working through the guides etc.

**Edit:  Here's the view code**

```
<%= link_to '<span class="pen icon"></span>Edit',
      content_url(:controller =>"video_playlists", :id => channel.video_playlist_id, :action => "edit"),
      :class => "button right" %>
```

Here are teh relevant pieces of the controllers:

```
class VideoChannelsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /videochannels
  # GET /videochannels.xml
  def index

    @video_channels = VideoChannel.roots(:order => 'order_num')
    @video_channels_parents = @video_channels.group_by {:parent_id}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @video_channels }
    end

  end

  # GET /videochannels/1
  # GET /videochannels/1.xml
  def show
    @video_channel = VideoChannel.find(params[:id], :order => 'order_num')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @video_channel }
    end
  end
```

end

```
class VideoPlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /video_playlists
  # GET /video_playlists.xml
  def index
    if !params[:with].nil?
      @video_playlists = VideoPlaylist.find(:all, :conditions => {:list_type => 'VideoShow'})
    else
      @video_playlists = VideoPlaylist.find(:all, :conditions => {:list_type => 'Section'})
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @video_playlists }
    end
  end

  # GET /video_playlists/1
  # GET /video_playlists/1.xml
  def show
    @video_playlist = VideoPlaylist.find(params[:id], :include => [{:video_video_playlists => :video}, {:videos => :asset}, {:videos => :content_image}])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @video_playlist }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in the view and controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did the line

```
VideoChannel.video_playlist_name
```

Come from? What's it doing? You're also calling a method on the class not an instance (sort of - Ruby isn't quite like this, but it's enough to explain).

Anyway:

Delegate is really for avoiding lots of train wreck code like this:

```
fred.jim.bill.xxx
```

You've said that they belong to each other - the relationships look like they're the wrong way round. Why are you creating the parent from inside the child? How are you going to have many video channels belonging to a given playlist?

I think you need to look at build and the relationship names. To gat past me maybe misunderstanding your model, lets have switch to a product that has many stock items:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_items
end

class StockItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This means that stock_item will have a column product_id.

So, say you're creating a product you'd do something like:

```
product.stock_items.build # :whatever the params are required
```

This automatically sets the id's for you and means you don't have to set id's. Then when you do product.save it will save all the related stock items too.

And in the view for this toy model, then if you were displaying one of the stock items, you'd use delegate to show the name of the product in the view without having to do lost of stock_item.product.name (for example).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't set up the relationship it was handed down.  Playlists technically the parent but they have a polymorphic relationship with Video Channels and Sections (something I haven't included here).  So the playlist will generally be either a VideoChannel or VideoShow(which links to sections).  I thought it was a bit complicated but I'm new here.                Switching the associations actually worked somewhat well, it passed the query through, but it passed the video_channel_id instead of another name it's supposed to have... not sure how to fix that.  The variables were correct.

Comment: I'd have to see the database to help you more. One thing though, I always use polymorphic with care - it's usually not worth the hassle. That's just my opinion, of course :)

Comment: This got me most of the way there, I had another more experienced rails programmer finish this up.  Thanks for you help.  Honestly, I don't understand using the polymorphic relationships.  Complex keys are a pain.  We use them in almost every table for some reason.